# Reassign saved global variable as not global

Tags: matlab, variables, global

I recently saved a variable I had declared as `global` and now I would no longer like it to be `global`. However, each time I load it, it loads as a `global` variable.  How I can change its `global` attribute?

e.g.

```
load 'madTec.mat'


whos global

 Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  madTec      1x107              960  madtec    global
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to just set a temporary variable (non-global) equal to your global variable, clear your global variable, set your matTec equal to the tmp variable, and then save your new matTec.mat and just reload it. It will no longer be a global variable.

```
tmp = madTec;
clear madTec;
matTec = tmp;
save('matTec.mat');
```